# How to convert int16 Pixel to uint16 Pixel without darkening the Image

Tags: c++, image-processing

I use the complexplanet.cpp Example from libNoise to create a *.raw File containing the Heights of the Terrain. The Problem is that the Data is singed and bigendian.
I could solve the bigendian Problem but when i try to convert to unsiged 16Bit the Values are wrong.

I used G'mic commandline tool for converting

Before conversion:
[image]

and after:
[image]

Maybe i should change the way the raw File is generated?

Here the Code:

```
int x, y;
uint8* pLineBuffer = new uint8[GRID_WIDTH * 2];
std::ofstream os;
os.open("terrain.raw", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
for (y = 0; y < GRID_HEIGHT; y++) {
    float* pSource = elevGrid.GetSlabPtr(y);
    uint8* pDest = pLineBuffer;
    for (x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
        int16 elev = (int16)(floor(*pSource));
        *pDest++ = (uint8)(((uint16)elev & 0xff00) >> 8);
        *pDest++ = (uint8)(((uint16)elev & 0x00ff));
        ++pSource;
    }
    os.write((char*)pLineBuffer, GRID_WIDTH * 2);
}
os.close();
delete[] pLineBuffer;
```

Maybe someone understand how this works. I got lost by the casting to uint16 than uint8 and than...

Comment: What does a negative pixel value represent?

Comment: I would assume below sea level. Casting to uint16 makes anything below sea level a very high mountain. You have to subtract INT16_MIN to shift all values.

Comment: yes, negatve values are below sea level. I will try that

Comment: What is the range of the float data?  How do you know it will fit in a 16-bit int?

Comment: min elevation is -8192.0 and max elevation is 8192.0.

Comment: Thank you Goswin, now its like it should be!